# Where does Puppet's Ruby DSL execution takes place?

Tags: puppet

Ruby DSL in Puppet is executed on puppet master or client?

I'm asking this because as I understood, templates are evaluated on master, when used in normal Puppet DSL. Is it the **same in Ruby DSL**?